# Javascript --- Hyphen between a character and a number inside a string

Tags: javascript, php, regex, string, preg-replace

Please help me to find a javascript function to convert a string like KX02AB1234 to KX-02-AB-1234. I want to add hyphen between a letter and number when ever it comes together..

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: No , I am not good with these regular expression stuffs

Comment: `str.match(/\d+|\D+/g).join('-')`

Comment: Show all possible cases. Explain statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP you can use lookarounds to find the gap between a letter and a digit (or vice versa) and replace that gap with a hyphen:

```
$str = 'KX02AB1234';
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])/i', '-', $str);
echo $str;
```

Output:

```
KX-02-AB-1234
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/jKBu0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method to extract digit combination(`\d+`) or non-digit combination(`\D+`) to an array and then use [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method to join them with a hyphen.

```
str.match(/\d+|\D+/g).join('-')
```

```js
const str = 'KX02AB1234';

console.log(str.match(/\d+|\D+/g).join('-'))
```